# Authenticating user request without pre auth filter in forgot password

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a separate rest module named 'x' where I have used spring security with basic auth filter(*username* and *password*) in complete module therefore any request hitting this rest services should be logged-in but I have one page for forgot password where I am mapping in the same x module due to this auth filter I am unable to proceed. If I am logged in and going to this page and using the services of x module then its working fine but not in case of logged out users.

I tried these thing for not working

```
<http pattern="/forgotpass" security="none"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/forgotPassword" access="permitAll"/>
<intercept-url pattern="/forgotPassword" filter="none"/>
```

--> **access="permitAll"** does not work since it does permit all url but still it will authenticate with filter
 and **filter="none"** is depricated not even able to start my jar when I put this thing.

**security="none"** gives 403 forbidden error sometimes or internal server error since I was changing the pattern "rest/forgotPassword" or "forgotPassword".

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by myself.

It was sequence that was having problem with.

I was using `<intercept-url pattern="/forgotPassword" access="isAnonymous()"/>`

after this `<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAuthority('USER')" />`

I just order the line by putting "/forgotPassword" url on top of "/**"

**Reason**: It was overriding the request pattern in sequence it came first therefore it didnt allow to pass because role was missing in forgotpassword